# Bootstrap nav bar is too short on pages with table

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mobile web app that uses Bootstrap.  Everything looks fine on a desktop; however, when I pull up certain pages on an iPhone 4S, the nav bar is much narrower than it should be.  Both of the pages that have this behavior have tables, so that may have something to do with it.

Screenshot: [image: here]

My shared `_Layout` Razor view looks like this:

```
@using FCTech.Quotes.Helpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default col-xs-12">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header float-left">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "logo navbar-brand" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                {
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Quotes", "Index", new {controller = "Quotes", salesPerson = AccountHelper.GetCurrentUserFullName()})</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Orders", "Index", new {controller = "Orders", salesPerson = AccountHelper.GetCurrentUserFullName()})</li>
                                }

                                @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && AccountHelper.AuthorizeAdmin())
                                {
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shipments", "ShipmentSummary", new { controller = "Admin", salesPerson = AccountHelper.GetCurrentUserFullName() })</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bookings", "BookingSummary", new { controller = "Admin", salesPerson = AccountHelper.GetCurrentUserFullName() })</li>
                                }

                                <li>
                                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                    {
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account")
                                    }

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body" class="content">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-right">
                <p>v @typeof(FCTech.Quotes.MvcApplication).Assembly.GetName().Version</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

And the body of one of the views that is displaying incorrectly looks like this:

```
@using System.Linq

@model IEnumerable<FCTech.Quotes.Models.OpenQuoteModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Open Quotes";
}

<head>
    <title>
        Open Quotes
    </title>
</head>

<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Open Quotes
    </legend>

    @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
    {
        <table id="OpenQuotesTable" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed table-striped tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuoteNumber)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuoteDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndUser)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalValue)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="@(item.QuoteDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30) ? "red" : string.Empty ) ">
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink(item.QuoteNumber.ToString(), "Detail", new { quoteNumber = item.QuoteNumber, productLine = item.Product, salesRep = item.SalesRep })
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.QuoteDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Customer)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.City)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.State)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EndUser)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Product)
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TotalValue)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }



</fieldset>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I might be wrong but I do not think you can put another set of head tags into the view if it is already referencing it from the layout. And normally you would declare the title via a ViewBag property such as `@ViewBag.Title`

Comment: Using a class="nav navbar-nav" in <ul> maybe creating the issue, also, try using a <table> if you want a table view, not <ul>. I know it generated the code for you, but I really think it would be better to use tables and <tr>, <td> and dont use the nav class out of the navigation bar

Comment: Neither of those are the issue.

Comment: @luk492 are you suggesting that I use a <table> for the Bootstrap navbar?  That completely breaks the navbar.  Bootstrap is expecting it to be <ul>

Comment: Is the menu bar as wide as your iPhone 4s (i.e. is the nav bar about 320px wide)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3 you should wrap your table tag into a .table-responsive div.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
  </table>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: This seems to have worked.  One more question, though: Is it possible to have the full table displayed on the screen at once, as well as having the navbar full-width?  When I wrap the table in a .table-reponsive div, it makes the table where I have to scroll to see the entire thing.

Comment: In your screenshot you have a container with 278px wide, and a content of 639px.  

The problem is not a technical one as it is conceptual.  You can't show everything in just 320px wide.  

But you can still use class="hidden-xs" to some th and td tags in order to display less information just for mobile, like this:

<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Im visible everyewhere</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">Im visible on every resolution except mobile</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
        <td>Everyewhere</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">Not in xs</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Samuel's answer,

This looks to be simply happening because Bootstrap's media query at that mobile level has a max-width on it with no hidden overflow while the table content exceeds this width.
Mobile tables are always a pain for front-end devs.

Other than the solution Samuel provided, you can always make your own custom media query to display the data in a cleaner way.

Personally, I suggest using jQuery DataTables for your display formatting. DataTables provides handling for smaller devices.
[DataTables Responsive example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/)

After having adding DataTables plugin and datatables responsive to your project, initialize it with this property turned on like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#OpenQuotesTable').DataTable( {

        responsive: true

    } );

} );
```